# Após pesquisa com keyup() editar em Modal e retornar lista com valor editado?

Tags: php, jquery

boa noite galera estou realizando uma busca com jQuery e o evento keyup() desta forma:

```
$('#colaborador').keyup(function(){

    var txtInput = $('#colaborador').val();

    if(txtInput.length == 0){
        $('#listPhone').html('');
        return;
    }

    var html = '';

    $.ajax({
        url : "paginas/listPhone.php",
        type : "GET",
        data : {busca: txtInput},
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += ...
                html += '</tr>';
            }
            $("#listPhone").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

até ai tudo transcorrendo bem, a cada letra digitada meu script vai no banco de dados e retorna um JSON com as linhas do conteúdo pesquisado, sem problemas.

após o retorno abro um modal com um formulário dentro, também sem problemas!

para gravar a edição que faço neste formulário utilizo o seguinte código:

```
$('#salvar').click(function() {
    var dados = $('#myForm01').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'paginas/editarRamal.php',
        async: true,
        data: dados,
        success: function(response) {
            location.reload(); //DÚVIDA AQUI
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

estou fazendo um reload da página, mas gostaria de saber como eu faria para ao clicar no botão gravar volte para a lista exibida só que com o novo valor no campo editado.

Answer (score 0):

Location.reload () atualiza a página atual. Se você utilizar essa função você perderá os dados da página. Neste caso eu aconselho não usar o reload.
Tente isso:
$('#salvar').click(function() {
    var dados = $('#myForm01').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'paginas/editarRamal.php',
        async: true,
        data: dados,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#colaborador").val (response);
//e se quiser vc fecha o modal por aqui com:
// $("seumodal").modal ("hide");
        }
    });
    return false;
});

Comment: entendi, mas não seria bem isso. precisaria que ele fizesse o keyup novamente para retornar as informações do banco de dados atualizadas. não sei se isso é possível.

Comment: Tem como sim. Mas como um ajax tem um delay para retornar o resultado, o usuário já teria dado outros keyups. Caso queira que eu demonstre mesmo assim como seria, é só falar...

Comment: Vinicius se tiver como me mostrar eu agradeço imensamente.